# Get response from web after page is finished loading, including JavaScript

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I would like to know how to get response from web after it's finished loading, including JavaScript.

This is what i have so far:

```
string url = "https://www.youtube2mp3.cc";
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("name=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE");
myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

Stream requestStream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
requestStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
string pageContent = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
myStreamReader.Close();
responseStream.Close();
myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```

Comment: Please include any code you have tried so far. SO is not a place to write your code for you, it is more a place to help you with problems you are having with code you have written already.

Comment: thank for notify me. i've updated my question

Comment: Where are you having a problem with your code? Are you getting any exceptions or errors?

Comment: no exception,  just when i get the response i'm missing the some values, this is due to javascript operation. for example if you'll run the code you 'll see that the line <a id="download" href="" rel="nofollow">Download</a> missing href's value but in the web (after javascript operation) the value exist

Comment: That is likely due to the attribute being empty. I am not sure if you can force an empty element attribute to appear in the response string. I will look around a little, but that is where you should start looking yourself as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. as i said when i'm using the web the line i've shown looking like this: <a id="download" href="http://hcqwb.yt-downloader.org/download.php?id=742247c3e8f94c2ba9c950c53c535bee" rel="nofollow">Download</a> you can see that we have the href but this is after the javascript run

Comment: JavaScript is executed by the client browser. `HttpRequest` does not execute your JavaScript for you. You should be able to see this by setting the initial `href` to `about:blank` instead of an actual empty value. Use. `href="about:blank"` instead of `href=""`.